# Fetch specific input element by attribure from Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have List of Check-boxes array and i want to get specific checkbox by specific attribute.

lets i have 20 checkedboxes in an array object. and each checkbox contains attribute `tradeId`

```
<input name="chkTrades" type="checkbox" tradeId="1">
```

i want to get only checkbox having tradeId=1

how to get it

Comment: [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: can you show us array object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select attributes in jquery pretty easily:

```
$('input[type=checkbox][tradeId=1]');
```

```js
console.log($('input[type=checkbox][tradeId=1]')[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="chkTrades" type="checkbox" tradeId="1">
<input name="chkTrades" type="checkbox" tradeId="2">
<input name="chkTrades" type="checkbox" tradeId="3">
```

Answer (score 1):

select check box by attribute

```
$('input:checkbox[tradeId=1]');
```